# Is there any way for typescript test files to import typescript source files when they have separate tsconfigs?

Tags: json, typescript, tsconfig

Sorry about the vague title here, it's one of those problems where I don't know what I don't know. Let me describe my directory structure:

```
root
  src
    tsconfig.json
  test
    tsconfig.json
  tsconfig.json
```

This is some legacy code. Normally I like to set up my project so that test files and source files are in the same directories, but that would be a massive change, so I'm trying to figure out how to get it to work the way it's already structured.

Basically, I want to be able to do this in a test file:

```js
// current file: test/downloader_test.ts
// downloader file: src/downloader.ts

import { Downloader } from "./downloader"; 

...
```

I can do this when source and test files are in the same directory, but in this case, they are in separate directories so I get an error on the import line about how "./downloader" doesn't exist.

There is a workaround that's already being used: instead, I could import from `../lib/downloader`, and it works, but I'd like to be able to refer to the typescript files. **Is there any way for test files to import typescript source files when they are under separate tsconfig.json files?**

I figure if a solution exists it's probably a tsconfig setting. These are what mine currently look like:

root/tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
    },
    "files": [],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./src"
        },
        {
            "path": "./test"
        },
    ]
}
```

root/src/tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "../lib",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "target": "es2019",
    "composite": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "types": ["node"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

root/test/tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "../libtest",
    "strict": false,
    "composite": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

I've also tried modifying that last file to add a

```json
  "references": [
    {
        "path": "../src"
    }
  ]
```

but that didn't change anything for me.

Comment: You can change the config of test/tsconfig.json so it can also transpile files from src/ directory, but if you're actually using the files that end up in `libtest` then it's probably not ideal. I'm pretty sure imports like `./downloader` are not possible; if anything you could alias it and then import it like e.g. `src/downloader`, but I don't know if you'd be interested in such solution. Plus it's really only the typescript part, I don't know how it would work with e.g. your test runner.

Answer (score -1):

You can use one config file in root folder only, and in `include`, you can add

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*" // According to your structure
]
```

other things in config file set according to your requirement and change the path.

```
import { Downloader }  from "../src/downloader”;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because the child tsconfigs have different settings.

Comment: Clarification: Using only one tsconfig won't work for me.